# Correction of hourly precipitation data with conditions

Tags: r

I´m working with precipitation data and want to implement a correction scheme. For this I have empiric constants which I have to apply to measurements within 12 hour intervals.

- If there is at least one precipitation measurement != 0 & != NA within a 12 hour range, then divide the constant by that amount of measurements and add the quotient to the measurements
- If there is no value > 0 & != NA within the interval, do nothing (or add 0)

I really do not have a clue how or where to start.

Here is some random precipitation data and the empiric constant is 0.14 [mm/12h]:

```
set.seed(1)
Time <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-05-15 07:00"), 
                  to = as.POSIXct("2012-06-15 07:00"), by = "hour")
Precipitation <- runif(Time, min=0, max = 20)
Precipitation[Precipitation >5] <- 0
Precipitation[Precipitation >4.5] <- NA
  
df <- data.frame(Time, Precipitation)
```

Edit: The output should look like the same table with a column added containing just the quotient.
Edit2: Thats an example of two 12 hour intervals which display what I want to achive. Sorry for beeing indistinct.

[image]

Comment: Can you also add what the expected output would look like?

Comment: I gave an example now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I got the correct understanding of your question, but consider the following code.

Edit: After you edited your question, I modified the code slightly. Now there's only the column with the quotient left. Below is the code that worked for you.

---

**Code**

```
Rows = as.numeric(rownames(df[seq(1, nrow(df), 12), ]))
Twelvehour_list = split(df, cumsum(1:nrow(df) %in% (Rows)))
Solution_list = lapply(Twelvehour_list, function(x)   
           {if(length(x$Precipitation[x$Precipitation > 0]) == 0) {
                                     x$newcol <- empiric_constant; x
                                } else {
                                  x$newcol <- 
                                      empiric_constant/length(x$Precipitation[x$Precipitation > 0 !is.na(x$Precipitation)]); 
                        x$newcol[x$Precipitation == 0] <- 0;
                        x$newcol[is.na(x$Precipitation)] <- 0;
                        x
                                }

                                    })
```

---

**Output**

```
 head(Solution_list[[10]])
               Time Precipitation newcol   
 118 2012-05-20 04:00:00      2.063685  0.125 
 119 2012-05-20 05:00:00      0.000000  0.000 
 120 2012-05-20 06:00:00      0.000000  0.000 
 121 2012-05-20 07:00:00      0.000000  0.000 
 122 2012-05-20 08:00:00      0.000000  0.000 
 123 2012-05-20 09:00:00      0.000000  0.000
```

The output is a list of `data.frame`s that each span 12 hours and contain the column of the quotient plus a column of the modified precipitation data, i.e. added with the empiric constant. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I specified my request with an example. Basically i want to devide the constant (0.14) by the amounts of observations !=0 & !=NA within 12 hour intervals and display the result in a new column in the rows of those observations.

Comment: Okay i see, thank you so far! Is there a way to merge the list to one data.frame similar to the original one?

Comment: And if an interval does not contain any measurement > 0 or != NA, then the whole constant is added to every measurement according to your solution. I try to fix it, but I´m really unexperienced with those codes...

Comment: This one works for me:`Rows = as.numeric(rownames(df[seq(1, nrow(df), 12), ]))
Twelvehour_list = split(df, cumsum(1:nrow(df) %in% (Rows)))
Solution_list = lapply(Twelvehour_list, function(x)   
{if(length(x$Precipitation[x$Precipitation > 0]) == 0) {
  x$newcol <- 0; x} 
  else {
    x$newcol <- empiric_constant/length(x$Precipitation[x$Precipitation > 0 & !is.na(x$Precipitation)]); 
  x$newcol[x$Precipitation == 0] <- 0;
  x$newcol[is.na(x$Precipitation)] <- 0;x}})`